# Logmein alternative that is fast to log in, secure & cheap?

Tags: remote-access

Does anybody know of a  free or very inexpensive remote access solution that is as secure as logmein, but that enables me to log in very quickly, by just clicking a single icon, without having to go through all the steps as free logmein?  I used to use VNC, but it is was getting hacked.  I need to implement the solution on dozens of PC's for many users.  If I were to use Logmein Professional, it would cost me at least $20 per year per user.

Comment: Related: [What’s the best Remote Desktop Application?](http://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Viewer is a solution for your problem :) However this is not the website you should be asking this question... Try superuser.com for a more comprehensive answer :)
This will get migrated to SU.