# Is there some (free) RDC/VNC solution that allows to connect to PC behind NAT without doing router configuration?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable and free remote desktop client and server?](https://superuser.com/questions/140103/reliable-and-free-remote-desktop-client-and-server)
>   [Is there a (free) way to set up remote desktop sharing without configuring the router?](https://superuser.com/questions/387736/is-there-a-free-way-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-without-configuring-the-r)

I'm trying to help a client remotely and he's behind NAT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable and free remote desktop client and server?](http://superuser.com/questions/140103/reliable-and-free-remote-desktop-client-and-server), http://superuser.com/questions/387736/is-there-a-free-way-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-without-configuring-the-r, http://superuser.com/questions/377990/most-reliable-remote-desktop-vnc-for-windows?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/170976/logmein-alternative-that-is-fast-to-log-in-secure-cheap?lq=1

Comment: Also, Software recommendation requests are considered off-topic for SU.

Answer (score 2):

You could do reverse ssh tunneling. Your client connects to your ssh server specifying something like `ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 your-pc`.
You can then connect to localhost:5900 with your vnc client and it gets tunneled back to the client (which obviously has to have a VNC server running on his computer).